# google map Version 2 not displaying -- android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I am using `google map` version2. I got the `API` key and place those in `manifest`. I can able to view the map in some devices, but when I compile the same app in different device, I get the blank screen instead to display the map. Can anyone guide me on this

```
    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

     if (myMap == null) {
         myMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                .getMap();
     }
    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    myMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: post your code manifest file and xml layout

Comment: yesterday same problem we are facing ,still not solved.

Comment: in which device you are not able to show map??? put you android manifest file & device Details. Because if device have't OPEN GL 2.0 or above then Google MAP v2 is not work...

Answer (score 0):

**activity_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    //modify below according to your requirement
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    ..
    ..
    ..
```

Add following in your manifest file:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.yourpackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.yourpackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

   <application
       ........ >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_api_key" />
```

Of course, you have to other manifest parameter like activity name and other.

Then you have to reference google play service library into your project.
Follow with this link to install google play service sdk [Install the Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install)

And then

```
Your Project--->Right Click-->Properites-->Android-->Add
```

Select google-play-services sdk that you import into your workspace using that i mention in above method

Finally, select your android sdk target to

> Google API Version 8

or other Google API version according to your requirement.

Further if you have any confusion, you can follow with this android official link:[Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

**UPDATED CODE:**

To make it work in lower version:

**activity_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**MyMapActivity.java**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment mapFragment =  (SupportMapFragment)
fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

Thanks !!

Comment: i done the same, when i change the api level to 8, i get error on fragmentManager. I hope this will works from api level 11. I can able to view the map some devices, but the same app shows blank map in some other devices.